# access denied in android studio for imported project

Tags: android, android-studio

I have changed the computer and now I have copied all the android project from my old computer to new one. I am opening a project in new computer and it give me this error while building. I have checked sdk and jdk paths they are proper. Am I missing something else here?

This is the error in android monitor.

:app:clean FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.

> Unable to delete directory: C:\Program Files\AndroidStudioProjects\myproject\app\build\generated\assets\shaders\androidTest\debug

Comment: plus this also..."FileNotFoundException: Unable to store project name: C:\Program Files\AndroidStudioProjects\myproject\.idea\.name (Access is denied) (moments ago)"

Comment: Open root project folder properties and set permissions for your user under which you are working

Comment: I am trying to move this file to e drive will that work?